No connection to the administartion panel. Django, JS
I'm having trouble connecting my snake game points to the model registered in admin. Then I want to use them to create a ranking.I dont use a JS on a daily basis so i use chatGtp to generate js code. I more or less understand the JS code. Its my code:
@require_POST
def submit_score(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)
    score = data.get('score')
    user = request.user if request.user.is_authenticated else None

    if user:
        player_username = user.username
        new_score = Score(player=user, point=score, player_username=player_username)
        new_score.save()

    return HttpResponse("Dobry wynik!")

class Score(models.Model):

    player = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    point = models.IntegerField()
    player_username = models.CharField(max_length=30) # Stores the username

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.player_username} - {self.point}'

function submitScore(score) {
  // fetch to send score
  fetch('submit-score/', { // The URL to change to the correct endpoint in Django
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken') // Required to Django to prevent CSRF attacks
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      score: score
    })
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error('Nie udało się zapisywać wyniku.');
  })
  .then(data => console.log('Wynik został zapisany:', data))
  .catch((error) => console.error('Błąd:', error));
}


I call the JS function in restart game. The game on the website works as it should

user could possibly be None but you still go on to send a HttpResponse.

I was return JsonResponse one with success one with error and it didn’t work
